# Noisy loss in distributed training in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

I am working on distributed learning in tensorflow through estimators API, and I always get below training loss graphs in tensorboard when comparing one-machine configuration (one ps and one chief on the same machine) and two-machine configuration (one ps and one chief on machine#1, one worker on machine#2).

[image]
[image]

Also when I download the graph data, I see that some steps are lost in two-machine distributed training case.
My model is defined in keras and I use the standard estimator functions for distributed training using dataset API in the following format (read_dataset is a custom function with generates training or evaluation dataset):

```
runConfig = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
        session_config=config,
        model_dir=log_dir,
        save_summary_steps=1,
        save_checkpoints_steps=train_steps
        )
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model, model_dir=log_dir, config=runConfig)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=lambda: read_dataset(...), max_steps=...)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda: read_dataset(...), start_delay_secs=1, throttle_secs=1, steps=None)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

What can be the cause for this noisy behavior and missing logs?

And another question: I assume that the above code implements data parallelism, in which input dataset is splitted between different machines and so each sample is used once during training but possibly by a different machine. Is it true? I am using Tensorflow 1.12 and 1.13.